# A Ruby On Rails-like migration tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I like that Ruby On Rails allows you to write a simple schema in which you can create and update a database using. Is there any tool like Ruby On Rails's migration, as I would like to use the method without using Ruby On Rails for my website development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use [ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) outside of a rails app. In fact, you'll find plenty of examples of people doing this, as in http://exposinggotchas.blogspot.com/2011/02/activerecord-migrations-without-rails.html

If you're using mongo as the persistent store, check out [mongrations](https://github.com/terrbear/mongrations) for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard this week on a little conference a talk about a tool called [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), a database change management tool. It is based on Java (I think), but manages the database migrations in an XML file. The change sets you have to write are similar to the migrations you can write with Rails. If you use Liquibase inside an IDE like Eclipse, you get completion for all relevant parts of the change sets. It supports a lot of databases out of the box, so it could be an alternative, especially that nowadays Java is installed everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Python [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's not Ruby though.